# Test transactions during development

Tags: monero-wallet-rpc, development

I want to also provide Monero as payment option on a website I have. To achieve this I will be using the JSON-RPC of wallet-rpc.

The documentation is pretty clear on how to use it. However, I can find nowhere on how to use test-cases on JSON-RPC during development.

Do I need to test it with real money and do a real transaction each time I am testing it during development?

Answer (score 0):

> Do I need to test it with real money and do a real transaction each time I am testing it during development?

No, you do not need to use real money for development / testing.

For development / testing purposes, use testnet (daemon and wallet flag `--testnet`). Mine some testnet coins (difficulty is far lower than mainnet, so it's quick to mine), then use your testnet coins for testing transactions on testnet.